# Passing data from one table to a block code - Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have a table dates_2019 with all the weekdays dates for 2019 as below:-

```
TS_RANGE_BEGIN      |TS_RANGE_END
2019-01-01 17:00:00 |2019-01-02 17:00:00
2019-01-02 17:00:00 |2019-01-03 17:00:00
2019-01-03 17:00:00 |2019-01-04 17:00:00
2019-01-04 17:00:00 |2019-01-07 17:00:00
2019-01-07 17:00:00 |2019-01-08 17:00:00
2019-01-08 17:00:00 |2019-01-09 17:00:00
```

My insert query as below:-

```
insert into report_2019(ab,app_name,status,sub_count,category,last_modified_timestamp)
with T as (
select id,ab,app_name,status,trunc(last_modified_timestamp),
     row_number() over(partition by id, ab order by p_message_id desc, message_id desc) lastest_status_order_id
          ,p_message_id
         ,LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP,reporting_purpose
from (
    select
     id,
     ab 
     , app_name,
 status
    ,p.message_id p_message_id
       ,s.message_id
    ,s.LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP, reporting_purpose
    from table_a s, table_b d, table_c k, table_d t,
        table_e p
    where s.LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP > to_timestamp('2019-01-01 17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
and s.LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP <= to_timestamp('2019-01-02 17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
    and .....
  ) a
)
select * from (
 select ab, app_name, status, count(*) subtotal, 
'Reporting' as v_category,trunc(last_modified_timestamp)
 from T  where lastest_status_order_id = 1
 and LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP <= to_timestamp('2019-01-02 17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
 group by ab,app_name,status,trunc(last_modified_timestamp))a order by ab, app_name;
```

The original idea was to join both the tables dates_2019 and T and get the results for the whole year as below:-

```
where s.LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP > c.ts_range_begin
and s.LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP <= c.ts_range_end
....
```

However the temp tablespace is low and i got the below errors:-

> [Error Code: 12801, SQL State: 72000]  ORA-12801: error signaled in
>   parallel query server P004 ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback
>   segment number 30 with name "_SYSSMU30_326584413$" too small

The option now is to insert the data one day at a time in a block.
Could you please help me with the solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Your error has nothing to do how much temp table space is available. That would generate error "ORA-01652 (which concerns an inability to extend the temp segment in a tablespace). Your error is with ROLLBACK space. ORA-01555: snapshot too old: is typically caused by  a long running transaction (as in hours) and committing too often.  The routine causing the problem is often NOT the one receiving the error.

Comment: Thank you for the response.How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove COMMIT out of the loop (if that's what you are doing).

Comment: Thanks..I am not using COMMIT.is there any other optimised ways to make it correct?